# Searching each line of a text file in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I have a textfile that get dynamically updated every so often with a string of text on     each line. What I want is a VB script that will search each line to see if it contains     "abc". There may be characters infront of and after so i need a wildcard like "*abc*". also case is not important. I am not very fluent in VB and have just been learning to do a small project at work.

So basically, I need something like

If any line in file.txt contains "*abc*" then send an email. I already have the code for sending the email that works fine.

I would also like to get a little more complicated with this and do something like

If any line in file.txt contains any line in file2.txt (with the same wild card requirement as above. so any line in file2.txt would need a wild card at the beginning and end of the line) then send an email.

The file2.txt would be a file manually updated on occasion to include more items to be searched for in file.txt so I wouldn't have to rewrite the script every time to include another search string.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim file1() As String = File.ReadAllLines("Path to file 1")
Dim file2() As String = File.ReadAllLines("Path to file 2")

Dim results As IEnumerable(Of String) = file1.Where(Function(f1) file2.Where(Function(f2) f1.Contains(f2)))

For Each item As String in Results
    '...
Next item
```

Comment: Looks like I'm getting "IEnumearble" is not defined with that.

Comment: It was a typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an over simplified example for the first part of what you're doing but you can get the rest of the way with it if you look up what it's using...

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sFileContents As String = String.Empty
        If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\temp\Info.txt") Then
            sFileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\temp\Info.txt")
        End If
        If sFileContents.Contains("asbsc") Then
            MessageBox.Show("yup")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("nope")
        End If
    End Sub
```